# TFS agents offline after running run command and closing the cmd to bring them alive

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, continuous-deployment

I have 20 agents and a couple of them are offline after we run on out of space on the tfs. I cleaned the _work folder to have more space, and it allowed me to bring at least the 80% of the agents back without doing nothing just clicking on the Update option over the application pool

[image]

Unfortunately as you can see I have a couple of them offline. I went through the tfs server and launch the cmd with the run command for the agent15

[image]

The funny thing here is that the agent is online now, **BUT if I close the cmd on the tfs server it goes offline again**. Can any one help me how to bring the agent online having the cmd opened?
A workaround is to reconfigure the agent and that's all, but I want to avoid that step, sure there is a better way than reconfiguring all my offline agents again.

Comment: That is a lot of Agents! I am assuming you have a high build churn which is what requires so many?

Comment: actually I just have one pipeline, and I need them all because I have more than one project(15 total) and also all of them are multitenant applications. So every time you run a build there is an agent running it, the same thing happens when you try to make a release, per environment you have 1 agent in charge, and I have more thant 9 environments. That is the reason, usually I have just 15 working

Comment: I would like to see the answer instead of someone that doesn't have one downvotes the question, I need help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the manually **update all agents**, all build agents within the selected pool will go offline temporarily and then come back online as soon as they are updated.

There are multiple reasons if a build agent is offline. The simplest and effectively way is **reconfiguring the offline agent.**

In your case, you could also try to restart the **Visual Studio Team Foundation Background Job Agent** in services, and if you run your agent as a service, also restart the agent service *VSTSAgent(machinename.xx)*. If it's not work, still recommend you to do the reconfigure option.

Comment: it worked restarting the agent through the windows services. Thanks!!!
Actually where I can find the documentation that supports that the agents run with that name on the windows services? thanks in advance

Comment: @Heinrich This is selected during the configuration of your agent. If you configured the agent to run as a service, it starts automatically. You can view and control the agent running status from the services snap-in. Run `services.msc` and look for "***VSTS Agent (name of your agent)***".  Source Link from official: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows#choose-interactive-or-service-mode

Answer (score 1):

As @Patrick-MSFT said, I would like to expand more the details. When you download the content of an agent and you try to establish the configuration, you need to do the following steps

1. Download the content
2. Run on the cmd as admin the config.cmd
3. Connect to the tfs address
4. Establish the agent pool
5. Name of the agent
6. Enter work folder(just
   press enter and by default you will get a _work folder created
   inside    the agent)

**7. Enter run agent as service? (Y / N)**

If you select Yes then you specify the credentials that the agent should use. At that point you have on your windows services as many services as agents you created. All of them with the prefix VSTS Agent(tfsserver.NameOfTheAgent)

Probably for some reason you had the services stopped. Just right click and restart or start the agent

[image]